# How to hard-code the url for JSON Parsing?

Tags: java, android, json

I would like to hard-code the url for JSON Parsing. Below here is my code:
I changed `SERVER_API_URL` to `TEST_API_URL` but it's not working.So, How to i put the hard-code url. 
My JSON Parsing coding is different from other online JSON Parsing. Please help me take a look. Thanks.

```
   private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    //Before running code in the separate thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...",
                "Loading exam timetable, please wait...", false, false);
    }

    //The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Context ctx = getActivity();
           SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, 0);

        try {
           // res1 = HttpClient.getData(ctx, Constants.SERVER_API_URL + "/timetable/semester/" + prefs.getString("Username", ""));
            res1 = HttpClient.getCode(ctx, Constants.TEST_API_URL + "/timetable/semester/" + prefs.getString("Username", "")); //Testing using with my own Url but not working
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    //after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //initialize the View
        if ((res1 != null) && (res1.getHttpCode() == 200)) {

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) timetable.findViewById(R.id.pager_day);



            String res = res1.getBody();
            week = new Gson().fromJson(res, WeeklyTimetable.class);

            if ((week.getMondayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getTuesdayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getWednesdayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getFridayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getThursdayActivities().size() == 0) && (week.getSaturdayActivities().size() == 0) &&
                    (week.getSundayActivities().size() == 0)) {
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) timetable.findViewById(R.id.semesterDay);
                rl.removeAllViews();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                rl.addView(View.inflate(timetable.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_layout_timetable_fail, null), params);
            } else {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter(res));
                if (day == 1) {
                    int finalDay = 6;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
                } else {
                    int finalDay = day - 2;
                    pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
                }

                pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
            }
        } else {

               RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)    timetable.findViewById(R.id.semesterDay);
            rl.removeAllViews();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rl.addView(View.inflate(timetable.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_layout_fail, null), params);
            TextView text = (TextView) timetable.findViewById(R.id.unavailable);
            String str = res1.getBody();
            int index = str.indexOf("\"}");
            text.setText(str.substring(12, index));
        }
    }
}
```

Below here is the class for *Constants.SERVER_API_URL* and *Constants.TEST_API_URL*

```
public class Constants {

/*  Hosting Setting */

/* Production */

public static final String SERVER_HOST = "Androidmobile.app.com"; //example
public static final String SERVER_API_URL = "https://Androidmobile.app.com/mobile/api";
public static final String SERVER_API_URL_HTTPS = "https://Androidmobile.app.com/mobile/api"; 


//Testing Dummy Data
public static final String TEST_API_URL = "http://kyawmyohtet.my3gb.com/ExamTimetable.php";
//End Testing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in your `Asynctask` class,

```
String url = null;
LoadViewTask (String url){
  this.url = url;
}
```

in your `onCreate` method or wherever you are creating the instance of `AsyncTask`,

```
LoadViewTask task1 = new LoadViewTask("Your URL");
```

you can then use variable `url` anywhere in your `AsyncTask` class to access your url.

Answer (score 0):

Below code change in your

```
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
```

to

```
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
```

and in *doInBackground()* method

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
        Context ctx = getActivity();

    try {

        res1 = HttpClient.getCode(ctx, params[0]); 
        //Testing using with my own Url but not working

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and call *LoadViewTask* like below with hardcode *url*.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, 0);
String str_URL = Constants.TEST_API_URL + "/timetable/semester/" + prefs.getString("Username", ""); 
new LoadViewTask().execute(str_URL);
```

this is hardcode *URL* passed in your *LoadViewTask* class when and where you call for response.